# How to move events from one Calendare to another (Different gmail)?

Tags: api, events, calendar, move

I am using calendar API to move the events from one Calendar to another totaly different gmail account and I am getting error.

```html
    404
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

When I am moving to secondary calendar on the same email no error is coming.

I have already gonethrough the doc which states I must have write permission for both calendar here how can I give permission using API.

Any example will be greatly appereciated.

Thanks,
Amit Singh